# how to skip over "Unable to find element with class name" error in Python with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The following code does what I need it to do except when it comes across a product that is missing a class_name, lets say product-price.  What I need help with is how to skip over that particular item and move onto the next one.  Currently I get the following error :

> "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'product-display-price'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"138","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:64186","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1473855489054\", \"value\": \"product-display-price\", \"using\": \"class name\", \"sessionId\": \"48018400-7a75-11e6-b0ab-5f6a864b5c88\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/48018400-7a75-11e6-b0ab-5f6a864b5c88/element/:wdc:1473855489054/element"}}"

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

b = open('csv/homedepotfridges.csv', 'w', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b,delimiter=',')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/appliances/dishwashers.html#!p=0&q=*%3Aprice-asc%3AcategoryPathHierarchy%3A2%2Fhd-classes%2Fl1-appliances%2Fl2-dishwashers')
items = []

for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item'):
    try:
        model = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-model')
        price = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-display-price')
        title = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-title')
        url = item.find_element_by_class_name('js-detail-link')

        items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
        print (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        a.writerow(c)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        model = 'n/a'
        price = 'N/A'
        title = 'N/A'
        url = 'N/A'
        items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
        print(model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href").text)
        c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
    a.writerow(c)


b.close()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Test/HomeDepotDishwashers.py", line 31, in 
>       print(model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute.text("href"))
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways to do that.  Have you tried any?

1) surround the line with a try - except https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item'):
    try:
        model = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-model')
        price = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-display-price')
        title = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-title')
        url = item.find_element_by_class_name('js-detail-link')

        items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
        print (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
        a.writerow(c)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        #here you can do what you want to do when an element is not found. Then it'll continue with the next one.

b.close()
```

2) use an if statement to check if this item is found. You do this by making a list of all those elements (find_elements_by_...) and see if the length of that list is greater than 0. eg:

Comment: I have tried the if statement but what I need is the statement to be able to see if there is nothing there to continue on to the next product and so on.

Comment: so put all of the stuff you may want to skip inside the if. Then with the if check if all the elements are found. Let me update my answer.

Comment: OK, so I have edited the code above to include to Element Exception.  What I need to do is to write to a CSV file.  I don't really care if the product if there are 'N/A' is the file.